# Sending HTTP response is blocked until shell command finishes

Tags: http, go, exec

Idea: there is a web server ready to receive messages that will trigger the execution of commands/tests on the server. I have started with a simple case where a simple `ping` is executed. The code below handles `POST` messages sent to `/ping` which contain the following json format:

```
{ "ip": "valid_ip_addr", "count": "4" }
```

The server will then run the command `ping -c 4 valid_ip_address`

**Desired outcome:** if the command can `.Start()` send back a `200 OK`. If there are problems, send back an error message.

**Problem:** I send a `200 OK` response right after checking that `.Start()` didn't give any errors, but this is being received after the command has finished.

**Code:** There are three functions: `main()`, `handler()` and `ping()`. The problem takes place in the last one.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

var err error

type Ping struct {
    Count string `json:"count"`
    Ip    string `json:"ip"`
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/ping", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":5050", nil)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    switch r.Method {
    case "POST":

        p := Ping{}

        err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&p)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("400 Bad request. Problem decoding the received json.\nDetails:\n%s\n", err.Error())
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), 400)
            return
        }

        fmt.Println("POST /ping ", p)
        ping(w, p)

    default:
        http.Error(w, "Only POST is accepted.", 501)
    }
}

func ping(w http.ResponseWriter, a Ping) {

    cmdName := "ping"
    cmdArgs := []string{"-c", a.Count, a.Ip}

    cmd := exec.Command(cmdName, cmdArgs...)
    cmdReader, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Error creating StdoutPipe for Cmd", err)
        http.Error(w, "Error creating StdoutPipe for Cmd\n"+err.Error(), 500)
        return
    }

    // the following is used to print output of the command
    // as it makes progress...
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(cmdReader)
    go func() {
        for scanner.Scan() {
            fmt.Printf("%s\n", scanner.Text())
            //
            // TODO:
            // send output to server
        }
    }()

    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Error starting Cmd", err)
        http.Error(w, "Error starting Cmd\n"+err.Error(), 500)
        return
    }

    // send 200 OK
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "ping started")

    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Error waiting for Cmd", err)
    }

}
```

**curl for testing**

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:5050/ping -d '{"ip": "127.0.0.1", "count": "4"}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use `select` with timeout waiting for an error. Check out the following code.

```
func ping(w http.ResponseWriter, a Ping) {

    cmdName := "ping"
    cmdArgs := []string{"-c", a.Count, a.Ip}

    cmd := exec.Command(cmdName, cmdArgs...)
    cmdReader, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Error creating StdoutPipe for Cmd", err)
        http.Error(w, "Error creating StdoutPipe for Cmd\n"+err.Error(), 500)
        return
    }

    // the following is used to print output of the command
    // as it makes progress...
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(cmdReader)
    go func() {
        for scanner.Scan() {
            fmt.Printf("%s\n", scanner.Text())
            //
            // TODO:
            // send output to server
        }
    }()

    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Error starting Cmd", err)
        http.Error(w, "Error starting Cmd\n"+err.Error(), 500)
        return
    }

    // not sending response here anymore. Using the channel instead

    errChan := make(chan error)

    go func(ec chan error) {
        err = cmd.Wait()
        if err != nil {
            errChan <- err
        }
    }(errChan)

    select {
    case err := <-errChan:
        http.Error(w, "Error: "+err.Error(), 500)
    // timeout 50ms just in case. But I presume you would get an error (if there is one in cmd) even before execution will get to this point
    case <-time.After(time.Millisecond * 50):
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "ping started")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will also take a look at `channels` because I am not very familiar with it. If I understand correctly, you send any potential errors to the channel. Then `select` blocks until one of the two cases can proceed...

Comment: @tgogos I would recommend to look into next materials:
https://gobyexample.com/channels
https://gobyexample.com/channel-synchronization
https://gobyexample.com/channel-directions
https://gobyexample.com/select
https://gobyexample.com/timeouts
https://gobyexample.com/non-blocking-channel-operations